# PHPMailer to send different mail to different person

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

How can I send different mail to different person? For example, in a contact form, a mail to myself notifying that a new data is added to database with the details. And another mail to the customer notifying that we have received his data (without details of the data which he have entered in the form). 
I can send only one mail to myself notifying me, but I want to send another customized mail  to the customer also

Comment: you already given answer, send another email to customer with required data. body and subject is diffrent so both the emal needs to be sent one by one.

Comment: I know that but I want to configure a automail. So I need to configure it in a single php file as there is only one POST can be done in a single click

Answer (score 0):

You could include something like the following in your script

```
$emailFrom = "Some One <do-not-reply@somedomain.com>";

$body1 = "First email body";
$subject1 = "Subject for first email";
$emailRecipient1 = "first.recipient@somedomain.com";

$body2 = "Second email body";
$subject2 = "Subject for second email";
$emailRecipient2 = "second.recipient@somedomain.com";

mail($emailRecipient1, $subject1, $body1, "From: $emailFrom");    
mail($emailRecipient2, $subject2, $body2, "From: $emailFrom");
```

Comment: I think it is for phpmail() function I want it for phpmailer with custom SMTP

Comment: I have got it. I used redirect at the end of 1st mail. So the code terminated after sending 1st mail. Thanks for your response